# Accessing Order History of All Customers Results in [Unauthorized access to order 'orderNo' in controller]

Tags: commerce-cloud

I'm a beginner in SFCC and I'm hoping someone can point me to the right direction. What I want to do is to get the orders of all customers in my controller (my end goal would be to sort the products by popularity depending on the logged in user's age group). Accessing other customer's order info would result in an error so my question is, is there like admin property or something that I can use for me to be able to access all of the orders of all customers? Thanks

> Wrapped java.lang.SecurityException: Unauthorized access to order 'orderNo' in controller

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default, multiple security options are enabled to prevent unauthorized access to orders that do not belong to you (or the session).

This is documented here:

https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/content/b2c_commerce/topics/admin/b2c_order_preferences.html?resultof=%22%6f%72%64%65%72%22%20%22%73%74%6f%72%65%66%72%6f%6e%74%22%20%22%61%63%63%65%73%73%22%20

More points explicitly 7 & 8:

> 7. Specify if access to orders from the Storefront is limited.
> 8. Specify whether to validate storefront order searches against the session customer. Set to Yes unless you have a specific reason to
>    disable this validation. Yes or No

Disabling these security options allows you to fetch all orders in the Storefront without security validation.

Disabling these options opens up your site to security risks that you need to take into account!

---

Looking at your original use case, I would advise against this as there is better to do this.

Salesforce Commerce Cloud B2C keeps track of sales by using something called "Active Data." You can use these values gathered in sorting rules to sort your products according to the sales.

https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/content/b2c_commerce/topics/active_merchandising/b2c_active_merchandising.html

https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/content/b2c_commerce/topics/active_merchandising/b2c_active_data_attributes.html?resultof=%22%61%63%74%69%76%65%22%20%22%61%63%74%69%76%22%20%22%64%61%74%61%22%20